# Is a nocturnal emission (Keri) a sin?

Tags: sexuality, sin, evening-night

Is a nocturnal emission, also known as keri, a sin? If it happens to you at night, is [teshuvah](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4729) necessary?

Comment: Why might you think it is or isn’t?

Comment: Rabbi Nachman of Breslov (d. 1810) compiled ten psalms to be recited as repentence for a nocturnal emission called the Tikkun HaKlali, so I would believe at least in his view it is a sin.

Comment: @Ezra I don't see how it could be. You didn't actually do anything so I don't see how it could be a issur. Also note that you can do teshuva for something that is not a sin. Like a nazir brings a sin offering even though what becoming is not only allowed but maybe sorta sometimes encouraged.

Comment: @Orion Ever heard of an unintentional sin?

Comment: @Ezra you mean a אונס? You're not chayiv for that. I believe it's a discussion if it's even considered like you've done anything. Unless you mean bishogeg/ negligence? In which case I think you're just chayiv for being negligent. Plus what could you have even done here?

Comment: Depends if you caused if by day or completely unavoidable

Answer (score 3):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([151:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.151.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) calls it a sin indeed, but an involuntary one.

> If, God forbid, you had a seminal emission at night, upon waking up
>   from your sleep you should wash your hands and say with a contrite
>   heart, "Master of the Universe I have done this unwittingly but it was
>   due to sinful thoughts and sinful reflections; therefore, may it be
>   Your will Adonoy, my God, and the God of my fathers, **to erase this
>   iniquity** [*avon*] through your great mercy, and save me from sinful thoughts,
>   and from similar occurrences forever and ever. Amein, so may it be
>   Your will." If you wish to avoid this **sin**, [...]

see [151:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.151.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and following for ways to avoid this issue.

[guardyoureyes.com](https://guardyoureyes.com/questions-and-answers/item/is-nocturnal-emission-keri-a-sin) expands on the issue and explains it is involuntary, there is no punishment involved but it requires *tshuva*

> A nocturnal emission is something that occurs by itself, against a
>   person's will, and therefore the person is not considered to have
>   committed a willful transgression and there is no punishment involved.
>
> Nonetheless, t'shuva is certainly appropriate, especially if a person
>   looked at things he shouldn't or had lustful thoughts during the day.
>   [...] The holy Baal Shen Tov teaches that if a person has an emission
>   without any cause or lustful thoughts, he should not worry because he
>   was under a sentence of death for some other sin, and now, because of
>   the great sorrow he feels in his heart over the wasting of semen, his
>   broken heart takes the place of death, and he is absolved from the
>   decree that was upon him.

see further [there](https://guardyoureyes.com/questions-and-answers/item/is-nocturnal-emission-keri-a-sin) for additional considerations

Comment: You should *not* worry because you were under a sentence of death for some unknown sin? While I would imagine it's nice to know you are no longer liable....wouldn't the prospect of b'shogeg death penalty level sins be at least a bit frightening?

Answer (score 1):

Our Sages teach us that these emissions come from thinking impure thoughts during the day. Based on that, you should have to repent

Comment: Adding a source would make this answer way better.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on sourcing your answers. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Renato that's not what that Gemara says. It just implies if you had a nocturnal emission due to daytime fantasies then you are at fault. No where does it say all nocturnal emissions are due to daytime fantasies! Indeed see Yoma 88 for a counterexample

Comment: @mbloch ^^^^^^^^^^^